# How can I make this renderer function continuous?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avkit

Hello I'm working with an AR Camera and once the camera identifies the anchored image it plays the video. Once the video finishes playing and return back to the camera I view the same anchored image again the video does not play. I want to be able to view the image and play the video as many times as possible.

***Here is my function to play the video.***

```
    func playVideo() {
    guard let videoLink = URL(string: "string") else {
        return
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoLink)
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
            self.present(controller, animated: true){
               player.play()
           }
        }
}
```

***Here is my function to recognize the image.***

```
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
    if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor{
        switch imageAnchor.name{
        case "image":
            playVideo()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Can someone help me out or point me in the right direction to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

When AVPlayer finish to present it send a system notification, so you can add the VC as a observer and when the notification will be sent in the function you can call again the play of the video.
This is the code do add the VC as a observer of the notification

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
```

Comment: Where would I add this notification?

Comment: In the viewWIllAppear you have to add this code, and pay attention to remove the observer in the viewWillDisappear

Comment: override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playVideo), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)

        let configuration = ARImageTrackingConfiguration()
        
        if let trackedImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "", bundle: Bundle.main){
            configuration.trackingImages = trackedImages
        }
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }

Comment: This is my viewWillAppear function.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create an object of "SKVideoNode".

```
videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: videoPlayer)
```

Then you can replay the video using the below code.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        guard let imageAnchor = (anchor as? ARImageAnchor) else {
            return
        }

        if imageAnchor.isTracked {
            videoNode.play()
        }
    }
```

Hope this will be helpful to you.